# how to use map function with (axios/classhooks) to read from API

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
class Verifry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      s: "0",
      user: [],
    };
  }
```

/* has title as attribute within the res.data*/
async componentDidMount() {
await axios
.get(`http://10.0.0.106:8080/kuwait_elections/api/about_us`)
.then((res) => {
const persons = res.data;
this.setState({ user: persons.data.title, s: "4" });
console.log(this.state.user);
});
}
componentDidUpdate() {
// this.state.user.map((u) => {
//   return

u

;
// });
}
render() {
return (

  {this.state.user.map((t) => {
  return
- {t.title}
  ;
  })}

);
}
}

```
export default Verifry;
```

Comment: can you please format your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your return is not correct. It should be like this.

```
{
  this.state.user.map(({title}) => { 
    return { title };
  })
}
```

Note: Please format your code properly to make it easier to understand.